# Reading an XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, getelementsbytagname, xmlnodelist

I'm using System.Xml to read a xml file in C#.
First I open the file (locally)... and use foreach to get the values, like this:

```
XmlNodeList titles = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("title");
foreach (XmlNode title in titles)
{
rowNews = new ListViewItem();
rowNews.Text = (title.ChildNodes[0].Value);
listView1.Items.Add(rowNews);
}
```

The problem is, I have many rss tags called title in my file, I'd like to read only those what are inside `<entry></entry>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ParentNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162396.aspx) and [LocalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.localname.aspx) properties:

```
if (title.ParentNode.LocalName == "entry") { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I like your way the best and it works! Thank you everyone else also!

Comment: The XPath approaches are good too. This is just a simpler way to do things if you are familiar with DOM and not with XPath.

Answer (score 7):

Usually its easier to use [XPaths](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) in this case, so your code would look something like this:

```
XmlNodeList titles = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//entry/title");
foreach (XmlNode title in titles)
{
rowNews = new ListViewItem();
rowNews.Text = (title.ChildNodes[0].Value);
listView1.Items.Add(rowNews);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `XDocument` in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

Then you can simply write `document.Elements("entry").Elements("title")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: look at how you iterate through the first "title" node.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like entry/title as your xpath?